Is it possible to dedupe child records by date field when uploading supplemental data to Oracle Responsys?
I am new to Oracle responsys so apologies for what might be a foolish question:
Within our account we have a one-to-one relationship between profile lists and profile extension data. As an example, we are trying to upload data as a profile extension to enrich our profile data but I am only able to join the data using fields that exist in both files.
What I want to do is the join the data using the field that exists both in the profile list and profile extension but dedupe the records in the profile list so that we only upload the most recent record. We have a date field that exists in the profile extension table but within Oracle profile list drop down there doesn't seem to be a way to update records based on date.
I have tried uploading records in the profile extension by matching the foreign key with the primary key in the profile list. Unfortunately, what happens is that duplicate records in the profile extension table are handled randomly as there is no way for me to prioritise the most recent records.
What I would like to is upload the profile extension data and:
If a foreign key in the profile extension matches a primary key in the profile list, and there are duplicate records in the profile extension, prioritise the most recent record by using a date field in the profile extension so that we only upload the most recent instance of the record.
